# Plotting points in R using google maps

Tags: r, google-maps

I'm trying to write a program using R to pull polling places location from the Google Maps API. Then I'd like to display said information in a map using R. Any kind of help would be useful. So far I've tried using the libraries ggmaps, maps and mapsdata. But essentially I want to use R to query google maps for polling places, google maps return that information then I want to redisplay it using R.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: do you have a `data.frame` in R with necessary latitude and longitude of polling places that you want to display? if you do, there is no problem to plot them using `ggmap() + geom_point()`, if you have only adresses, but not coordinates, then there will be necessary to request them from Google Maps API with `geocode` function. Please explain how have you tried to watch polling places? (I guess, in browser, then maybe provide link which shows the necessary picture with a map and polling places)

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty straightforward using the packages you mentioned.  The `geocode` function may well do what you need.  For example

```
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
map("usa")
points(geocode(c("boston", "washington DC", "new york")), cex=3, col=rainbow(3))
```

[image]

Comment: So I tried something similar. Maybe I misunderstood the syntax but what I was looking for was have are request polling place in/near state. Google maps then replies with a map of said state with the plot points of ask the polling places on it. Does that make better sense?